# Results of lm() function with a dependent ordered categorical variable?

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to understand [Ben Bolker's answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m)

First, we create a data frame:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=sample(1:4,size=30,replace=TRUE))
d$y <- rnorm(30,1+2*d$x,sd=0.01)
```

Then Mr. Bolker says:

#### x as ordered factor

```
coef(lm(y~ordered(x),d))
##  (Intercept) ordered(x).L ordered(x).Q ordered(x).C 
##  5.998121421  4.472505514  0.006109021 -0.003125958
```

Now the intercept specifies the value of `y` at the *mean* factor level (halfway between 2 and 3); the `L` (linear) parameter gives a measure of the linear trend (not *quite* sure I can explain the particular value ...), `Q` and `C` specify quadratic and cubic terms (which are close to zero in this case because the pattern is linear); if there were more levels the higher-order contrasts would be numbered 5, 6, ...

---

My question is, what does the regression formula look like explicitly?

I thought `lm()` makes a model like this:

> y = 5.9981 + 4.4725 (x_1) + 0.0061 (x_2) - 0.00312 (x_3)

where, since the `x_i` are categories, they can only be either 0 or 1.

I do not understand what quadratic and cubic terms have to do with a linear model. Even so, squaring/cubing any of the variables would not make a difference, since 0 ^ 3= 0 and 1^3 = 1.

Comment: No answers yet, and I don't have time to write a full one, but as a starting place, see `contr.poly(4)` for the numerical definition.

Comment: and compare to the default `contr.treatment(4)`; you'll see that while the default is to code with just 0/1, the polynomial contrasts are not simply 0/1.

Comment: Google "polynomial contrasts".

Answer (score 14):

In this case, what `lm()` is doing is converting your "categorical" variable into a numeric sequence in order.

To make this clearer, I'll adapt Bolker's code a bit to make the X variable more obviously categorical:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=sample(1:4,size=30,replace=TRUE))
d$y <- rnorm(30,1+2*d$x,sd=0.01)
d$x = factor(d$x, labels=c("none", "some", "more", "a lot"))
coef(lm(y~x, d))
#  (Intercept)       xsome       xmore      xa lot 
#     3.001627    1.991260    3.995619    5.999098
```

So here, the mean of `x=None` is in the intercept, and the deviation from that is indicated for each category.

```
coef(lm(y~ordered(x), d))
#  (Intercept) ordered(x).L ordered(x).Q ordered(x).C 
#  5.998121421  4.472505514  0.006109021 -0.003125958
```

Conceptually, what's happened here is that the `ordered()` function converted `x` into `newx` using (something similar to):

```
if (x=="None") newx=-.67
if (x=="some") newx=-.22
if (x=="more") newx=.22
if (x=="a lot") newx=.67
```

and then it fitted (something like) the model:
$$y = a + b_0 \times newx + b_1 \times newx^2 + b_2 \times newx^3$$

where you have linear $newx$, quadratic $newx^2$, and cubic $newx^3$ components.

Note, I said that it's **something like** that, because the problem with the model described there is that $newx$, $newx^2$, and $newx^3$ are not at all independent. What `lm()` does instead is uses a set of contrasts generated by `contr.poly(4)`. These contrasts ensure orthogonality, so that the linear, quadratic and cubic components are independent. But the principle is similar - when fitting ordered factors, `lm()` fits a linear, quadratic, cubic, etc... component.

You can see this by comparing:

```
coef(lm(y~ordered(x), d))
#  (Intercept) ordered(x).L ordered(x).Q ordered(x).C 
#  5.998121421  4.472505514  0.006109021 -0.003125958
```

with

```
contrasts(d$x) <- contr.poly(4)
coef(lm(y~x, d))
#  (Intercept) ordered(x).L ordered(x).Q ordered(x).C 
#  5.998121421  4.472505514  0.006109021 -0.003125958
```

Exactly identical. So if you want a fuller understanding of what happened, take a closer look at `contr.poly()` and orthogonal polynomial contrasts in general.

One thing to note is that there is an implicit assumption hidden in here: the difference between each two levels is assumed to be equal. So "None" is as far from "some" as "some" is from "more", and "more" is from "a lot".

Comment: Thanks. Where did the -.67, -.22, .22, .67 values for newx come from? And why is taking the higher-order polynomials the right thing for studying order?

Comment: Great answer, and good follow up question, had the same one. The -.67, -.22, .22, .67 values seem to come from the .L part of contr.poly(4) > contr.poly(4)[,".L"]
[1] -0.6708204 -0.2236068  0.2236068  0.6708204