# Modifying ordered factor estimates in linear model

Tags: r, regression, modeling, ordinal-data, lm

My question starts on previous answered questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m/25736023#25736023

[Results of lm() function with a dependent ordered categorical variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339382/results-of-lm-function-with-a-dependent-ordered-categorical-variable)

so we have a linear regression with an ordered factor

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=sample(1:4,size=30,replace=TRUE))
d$y <- rnorm(30,1+2*d$x,sd=0.01)
d$x = factor(d$x, labels=c("none", "some", "more", "a lot"), ordered = TRUE)
coef(lm(y~x,d))
 (Intercept)          x.L          x.Q          x.C 
 5.998030948  4.476055799 -0.001380486  0.003362548
```

The answer to the second of the questions above explains how this coefficients are obtained, by means of replacing the values of `d$x` by the corresponding values of `contr.poly(4)` to ensure orthogonality among the linear, quadratic and cubic polynomials.

My doubt is how should I proceed if I just one to include the linear or the linear and quadratic polynomials in the model.

If I wanted to include only the linear term, I would do `d$x = as.integer(d$x)`, obtaining same p-values but different betas than using the values of `x.L` given by `contr.poly(4)[, ".L"]`. Is this a right way to proceed or it would be preferable to use `x.L`? Are there other preferable options?

And what if I want to include also the quadratic term? Should I use `contr.poly(4)` even if I do not need orthogonality with the cubic polynomial?

Thank you!